# Find .jar file of other java process

Tags: java, windows, process, jvm

Basically, given a jvm (the process named `Java (TM) Platform SE binary`) process id, can i find the underlying .jar file that the jvm is running? Can I do this from other languages (non-java)? I know that the jps tool in the JDK can list the e.g. the starting arguments for the jvm process, but it does not list down the .jar file path, most times it just lists down the package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> given a jvm process id, can i find the underlying .jar file that the
>   jvm is running?

Yes. Use [`jcmd`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html) utility:

```
jcmd <PID> VM.command_line
```

> Can I do this from other languages?

Yes. See [`jattach`](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) for the C implementation.

Comment: jcmd gives "Operation jcmd not recognized!" when I try to do that. The program I was trying to search on was netbeans which uses its own bundled jvm, perhaps this was the issue? I will try jattach and report back.

Comment: @EnigmatrixAtheros `jcmd` appeared in JDK 7. Your target JVM is probably older. `jattach PID properties` should help.